# c# console framework.net How do i go to the start of my program at the beginning of my login page without closing my program

Tags: c#, console, frameworks

I need to make it so when I logout the program loops back to the start with resetting the data of the login (restarting the loop) and with my attempts resetting to 0, and having to login again, right now I use environment exit but I am not allowed to use that. This is for a school project I am really new to c#

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace GIMPIES1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static bool ingelogd = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {
            //Zorgt ervoor dat de schoenen in de voorraad begint met 0//

            int aantal1 = 0;
            int aantal2 = 0;
            int aantal3 = 0;
            int aantal4 = 0;

            //Login pogingen teller// 
            int loginAttempts = 0;

            // 3 pogingen //
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                //inlogpagina// 

                string login = "inkoop";
                string password = "gimpies_inkoop";

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Voeg je gebruikersnaam in.");
                string inputlogin = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Voeg wachtwoord in");
                string inputpassword = Console.ReadLine();

                //Hier checkt die of inputlogin gelijk is aan login en inputpassword gelijk is aan password. Als het gelijk is dan gaat die door en anders gaat die naar de else if.//

                if (inputlogin == login && inputpassword == password)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Inloggen gelukt");
                    Console.WriteLine("Klik op enter om door te gaan");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    //while loop zorgt ervoor dat wnr ik op enter klik in een schoenvoorraad dat die niet uit gaat loggen maar dat die in de menu blijft//
                    while (inputlogin == login && inputpassword == password)
                    {
                        Menu();
                    }
                }
                //Als inputlogin niet = aan login/ inputpassword niet = password dan voegt die 1 poging toe 1 waarde toe aan loginattempts++//
                else if (inputlogin != login && inputpassword != password)
                {
                    //voegt die 1 poging toe aan totaal//
                    loginAttempts++;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Inloggen niet gelukt");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                //laat de resultaat zien//
                if (loginAttempts > 3)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Programma gaat afsluiten u heeft al uw pogingen gebruikt. ");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }

            //menu nadat je goed hebt ingelogd//
            void Menu()
            {
                //opties menu//
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("1. Voorraad schoenen bekijken");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Schoenen inkopen");
                Console.WriteLine("3. uitloggen");
                Console.WriteLine("Maak uw menukeuze en klik op ENTER");
                int schoenvoorraad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                switch (schoenvoorraad)
                {
                    //paginas in de menu//
                    //Nadat je keuze 1 maakt in de menu//
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Nike, Airmax");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Nike, Jordan");
                        Console.WriteLine("3. Adidas, yeezys");
                        Console.WriteLine("4. Converse, Allstars");

                        Console.Write("Kies je schoenensoort");
                        int keuze = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        //Schoenen en hun informatie//
                        switch (keuze)
                        {
                            //int is 0 en aantallen zorgen ervoor dat het start op 0 en dat je het kan vullen wanneer je wilt.//
                            case 1:
                                Console.WriteLine("Merk. Nike");
                                Console.WriteLine("Type. Air Max");
                                Console.WriteLine("Maat. 42");
                                Console.WriteLine("Kleur. Rood");
                                Console.WriteLine("Aantal " + aantal1);
                                Console.WriteLine("Prijs. 50,00");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Console.WriteLine("Merk. Nike");
                                Console.WriteLine("Type. Jordan");
                                Console.WriteLine("Maat. 41");
                                Console.WriteLine("Kleur.Zwart");
                                Console.WriteLine("aantal " + aantal2);
                                Console.WriteLine("Prijs. 140");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Console.WriteLine("Merk. Adidas");
                                Console.WriteLine("Type. Yeezys");
                                Console.WriteLine("Maat. 40");
                                Console.WriteLine("Kleur. Grijs");
                                Console.WriteLine("aantal " + aantal3);
                                Console.WriteLine("Prijs 230");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("Merk. Converse");
                                Console.WriteLine("Type. Allstars");
                                Console.WriteLine("Maat. 43");
                                Console.WriteLine("Kleur. Wit");
                                Console.WriteLine("aantal " + aantal4);
                                Console.WriteLine("Prijs 165");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    //Schoenen inkopen//
                    // wat je ziet wanneer je schoenen probeert in te kopen//
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Nike, Airmax");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Nike, Jordan");
                        Console.WriteLine("3. Adidas, yeezys");
                        Console.WriteLine("4. Converse, Allstars");
                        Console.WriteLine("Kies de schoenen dat je wilt kopen");
                        //wat je ziet wanneer je een optie kiest van de schoen dat je wilt inkopen//
                        //aantal zorgt ervoor dat je het kan inkopen//
                        int inkoop = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        switch (inkoop)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Console.WriteLine("Hoeveel aantal schoenen wil je inkopen? = " +  aantal1);
                                aantal1 = aantal1 + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Console.WriteLine("Hoeveel aantal schoenen wil je inkopen? = " +  aantal2);
                                aantal2 = aantal2 + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                break;
                                
                            case 3:
                                Console.WriteLine("Hoeveel aantal schoenen wil je inkopen? = " +  aantal3 );
                                aantal3 = aantal3 + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("Hoeveel aantal schoenen wil je inkopen? = " + aantal4);
                                aantal4 = aantal4 + Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                                break;
                            //wanneer je een schoen hebt gekozen gaat die weer terugloopen naar de menu met een while loop//
                        }

                        break;
                    case 3:
                    
                    break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried environment exit, system exit and appication.restart

Comment: Please present your question and related data so it is as easy as possible for us to read. There's simply no justification for those great wads of empty space in your code, making us scroll for no reason.

Comment: It's called a loop. You would have the login at the top of the loop and, if successful, call a method that contains all the logic for your app. When the user logs out, that method should return and that will end that iteration of the loop and you'll start again with the login.

Answer (score 1):

Now I tried to stay as close to your original code as possible/do minimal changes.

To the start of the Menu method I added `bool hasLoggedOut = false;`
and at the end of the method I added `return hasLoggedOut`. Naturally this also means that I changed Menu from void to bool.

Then in your case 3 (where you wanna log out) I simply set hasLoggedOut to true

```
case 3:
    hasLoggedOut = true;
    break;
```

And the part where you call the Menu I changed to

```
bool keepRunning = true;

while (keepRunning)
{
    keepRunning = !Menu();
}
                    
i = -1;
loginAttempts = 0;
continue;
```

continue simply tells a loop to skip the rest of the actions and start at the top as if it had run through once. the i=-1 is there so that after the continue call the `i++` turns i to a 0